Odd fluff found around bathroom fan
I am at a new place and am trying to change out the bathroom fans. The light cover in one had some stuff in it that I assumed was just dead bugs. Upon taking off the cover it was some brown fluff I don’t recognize. Once I had the whole unit out I found more of the material around the housing. Is this just dead bug shells or is it asbestos/a material I need to address? Additionally. If it is bug shells should I be concerned and is there a way to mitigate them returning?
Images of the material here:
https://imgur.com/a/bath-fan-k4KFBs4

cobwebs with attached dust

That is dust and lint. Commonly found is any fan that has been in use for some time. It is on top of the spray texture used on the ceiling.
Only a lab test can tell if there is asbestos, but what you are seeing can be found in the bath fans of most homes in America.
